# Colocar a data no formato americano com substring

Tags: c#

Como colocar a string **22012018** que é uma data no formato americano pra salvar no banco de dados?
O código abaixo me retornar o valor:

> 2018-22-01

Ou seja, ANO-DIA-MÊS

O certo seria ANO-MÊS-DIA

```
 EstFData = Path.GetFileName(arquivo).Substring(4, 8).Trim();
 EstFData = EstFData.Substring(4, 4) + "-" + EstFData.Substring(3, 2) + "-" + EstFData.Substring(0, 2);
```

Comment: Um detalhe: para salvar no banco, você pode informar apenas o `DateTime` e não a string, assim o próprio banco se encarrega do formato que ele estiver trabalhando

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se preferir usar um código menos verboso, você pode tentar desta forma:

```
EstData = DateTime.ParseExact(
        EstData, 
        "ddMMyyyy", 
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
    .ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Comment: Estava fazendo no fiddle, mas como já colocou, deixo aqui: =] https://dotnetfiddle.net/Zk1acB

Answer (score 1):

Creio que da forma que digitou está correto, apenas o posição está incorreta, tente desta forma:

```
EstFData = EstFData.Substring(3, 4) + "-" + EstFData.Substring(2, 2) + "-" + EstFData.Substring(0, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Utilize o método DateTime.ParseExact para converter em datetime.
Segue exemplo:

```
DateTime dataConvertida = DateTime.ParseExact("22012018", "ddMMyyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
```

Para conseguir esta data no seu código, entendo que seria assim:

```
string EstFData = Path.GetFileName(arquivo).Substring(4, 8).Trim();
DateTime dataConvertida = DateTime.ParseExact(EstFData, "ddMMyyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
```